# How to utilize tail-padding?

Tags: c++

Look at this simple code:

```
struct Foo {
    short a;
    char b;
};

struct Bar: Foo {
    char c;
};
```

With current compilers, `sizeof(Bar)` is 6. It is normal, as `sizeof(Foo)` is 4, and 
`Bar::c` gets added to it, we got 5 bytes, and because `Bar`'s alignment is 2, it gets a size of 6.

However, if `Bar` weren't standard-layout, then the compiler would be allowed to put `c` into the tail-padding of `Foo`, so `sizeof(Bar)` would be 4.

What is the most idiomatic way to achieve this (less intrusive modification, clearest way)?

Comment: I have a feeling whatever you do it is going to cost you more then the wasted byte of memory.

Comment: lol - guess #pragma pack was the answer they wanted.  Ah well...

Comment: @NathanOliver: why? I'd like to make `Bar` non-standard layout, so the compiler will be able to optimize it. It's just a flag to a type, whether it is standard-layout or not. I'd like to remove this flag, so `Bar` becomes a non-standard-layout type.

Answer (score 1):

> With current compilers, `sizeof(Bar)` is 6.

That is a factually wrong assumption, even if you could define what a "current compiler" is. "Standard-layout" is also a meaningless buzzword.

If I understand correctly what you're trying to achieve, `#pragma pack` is the answer. You can instruct the compiler on a class by class basis what byte packing to use.

Typically for network transfer you'd probably want to use a packing of 1, and for anything else (memory operations, storage, etc) just let the compiler do it for you. It will typically pad your fields to be on word boundaries for maximum access performance (not to be confused with caching performance).

Comment: Yes, using `#pragma pack`

Comment: I'm not sure if I would call Standard-layout a meaningless buzzword.  It is defined in the standard and offers certain guarantees about the objects layout.

Comment: The only hard guarantee it offers is that it can freely ignore `#pragma pack` if the compiler wants

Comment: No, I don't want #pragma pack. As I've said, I'd like to convert my type to a non-standard-layout type, so the compiler does this optimization already without using any non-standard extension.

Answer (score 1):

I've found a simple way to do this:

```
struct Empty { };

struct Foo: Empty {
    short a;
    char b;
};

struct Bar: Foo {
    char c;
};
```

Here, `sizeof(Bar)` is 4, and `Foo` is still a standard-layout class (which wasn't a requirement from my part, but nice to have).

Comment: You could also do 

`struct Foo {
    short a;
    [[no_unique_address]] char b;
};

struct Bar: Foo {
    char c;
};`

`no_unique_address` will allow the data member to be overlapped with other non-static data members or base class subobjects of its class.